# ActiveX not raising EOleException

Tags: delphi, exception, activex

I've made two activex component in Delphi XE2 in  separate projects. One of the components works perfectly, and every exception it throws gets masked as EOleException. On the other activex component, the exceptions are not masked, they are thrown as their original type. The client is a delphi XE program.

When the activex component throws the original exception, the next call to any other method from the component throws an Access Violation exception in places it shouldn't, like setting a local string variable with a value. It is a very strange behaviour.

I compared both projects .ridl file, compiling options, .dproj file, and couldn't find the culprit.

Anyone know the reason for this difference/ strange behaviour?

thanks

Edit: Some code

Component 1 that works (masks all exceptions to EOleException)

```
TspdMyClassX = class(TActiveXComponent, MyInterface)
```

...

```
initialization


TActiveXComponentFactory.Create(
    ComServer,
    TspdMyClassX,
    CLASS_spdMyClassX,
    1,
    '',
    0,
    tmBoth);
```

The other component that do not throw EOleException have a different interface, but the rest of the code is the same (initialization, parent class TActiveXComponent)

Comment: Please show some actual code.

Comment: Have you compared the order of the units included in the `uses` clause.  If two included files both handle exceptions, then perhaps it is using code from different units between the two projects.  It uses the code it finds first, starting with the last unit in the `uses` clause and working backwards from there.

Comment: I've found out that if I define a method that do not take any parameters and have no return value, the component masks the exceptions generated inside the method with EOleException. When the method have a return value or parameter, the exception don't get masked. I am doing the same project on delphi 7 from ground zero to see if it is some delphi xe2 related bug.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the problem is with delphi XE2 generated .ridl / .tlb files. I redesigned the component using delphi 7, then opened the project in delphi xe2 and only compiled/build in it (no edit in the .ridl, no changes in TLB in delphi xe2). All exceptions were being correctly masked by EOleException and the problem is solved

Comment: After comparing the files with the version designed in Delphi XE2 I noted that some methods are generated with "stdcall" in xe2 while delphi 7 generates all methods with "safecall".

Comment: here is some info I found on google http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=86698

Comment: from the link above, "The safecall convention implements COM error and exception handling."